# cakePHP : x_with in action / function causes errors... repeatable?

Tags: cakephp

In a controller, make a dummy action, name it like stackoverflow_with_something()//the WITH part is important

Create the view stackoverflow_with_something

Load up the page in a browser. Get a 'missing view error'

Take out the _with, try again. No error.

I havent seen any documentation on this, whats the deal?

short version : Why does xxxxx_with_xxxxx crash cakePHP, but xxxxx_xxxxx dosent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problems here, tried with the following:

/app/controllers/foos_controller.php:

```
<?php
class FoosController extends AppController {
    var $uses = null;

    function bar_with_yadda() {
    }
}
?>
```

/app/views/foos/bar_with_yadda.ctp:

```
Hello
```

requesting `/foos/bar_with_yadda` returns no error.

Comment: Well thanks anyhow... Ill have to dig into it more here then, thank you for confirming its on my end and not a core bug. :-)